# SceneKit: save scn file to disk

Tags: scenekit, xcode13

Goal: save scn file to disk.

What I did:
Trying to use this API:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write

Problem:
Get this error:
AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 248096 ===
The operation couldn’t be completed. (MDLErrorDomain error 0.)

Any help is much appreciated!

```
  let scnScene = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/Ship")!
```

```
//get documents URL
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
```

```
  //save scn to disk
    func saveSCNFileToDisk() {
        let url = getDocumentsDirectory()
        scnScene.write(to: url, options: nil, delegate: nil) { float, error, pointer in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.scene = url.absoluteString
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are missing a file name + extension (.scn) which should be specified by the url? It seems like you only specify a folder?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get this. Where should I specify  name + extension (.scn)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should specify the file scheme as described in the docs

```
//save scn to disk
func saveSCNFileToDisk() {
    let url = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("someFleName.scn)
    scnScene.write(to: url, options: nil, delegate: nil) { float, error, pointer in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.scene = url.absoluteString
        
    }
}
```